# Free sshd for windows

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm not too keen on installing cygwin on my servers just to have sshd support. Can you recommend standard-compliant, and preferably free, alternatives to OpenSSH on Windows servers?

Comment: Cygwin is really the way to go. You don't have to install too much to make it work.

Comment: http://www.chinese-watercolor.com/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html - that's the guide I used, worked as advertised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [do you know good alternative of copSSH - free one](http://serverfault.com/questions/337207/do-you-know-good-alternative-of-copssh-free-one)

Answer (score 2):

[WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)

Free for personal, non-commercial use.  Although honestly, it's not expensive to license.  I run it on a number of my servers.

Comment: By far, the best choice.  And use Tunnelier as the client for tunneling RDP, FTP, and console sessions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several SSH Server available for Windows Server :

- [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)
- [Free SSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/)
- [KpyM](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm)
- [Sysax](http://www.sysax.com/server/index.htm)

I suggest FreeSSHd that is a good free ssh server for windows.